# Is this the correct way to initialize 'setPin' method in ScrollMagic?

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

I want to know that if the following code is correct for utilizing ScrollMagic in the desired fashion. I'm trying to pin the elements by using this method, but it's not working.

**Javascript:**

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

$('.caption, .backcap').each(function(){

var tween= TweenMax.from($(this), 1, {autoAlpha:0,x:'+=30'})


var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement:(this)
})

.setPin()
.setTween(tween)
.addTo(controller);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slide-1" class="slide">
<div id="pin" class="caption">
<div id="backcap" class="backcap"><div class="intro_text"><h1 class="uppercase">blender</h1></div></div>
<div id="backcap" class="backcap"><div class="intro_text"><p>3d art</p></div>
</div></div></div>
```

What changes are necessary in order to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `id` of the element you want to pin in `setPin()` method.

for your case, this should work.

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
   triggerElement:(this)
}) 

   .setPin('#pin') 
   .setTween(tween)
   .addTo(controller);
});
```